# How to go from space group to crystal structure?

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I'd like to easily be able to define a group of lattice points for any crystal structure, with or without a basis.

It seems the space group is the most commonly given quantity describing the structure of a crystal, so I'd like to learn how to build any structure given the space group.

For example, how can I use the space group to extract the lattice and basis vectors for any structure? Or is there an easier way to do this? I would simply just like to know the lattice and basis vectors for any arbitrary structure in fractional and cartesian coordinates. Is the space group the most general way to do this?